# c# repeating a private void button click

Tags: c#, button, private, void

How do you repeate a private void button click??

code:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox4.Text == "BTC")
        {
            WebClient c = new WebClient();
            var data = c.DownloadString("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd");
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
            richTextBox1.Text = ("BTC Price: " + o["ticker"]["price"]);
```

if the data on the text box is "BTC", then the btc price is displayed on a richtextbox.

But how do you make it repeat, so that every price change is displayed on the richtextbox?

Comment: Why don't you move the relevant code into a separate method?

Comment: How do you plan to test for the price changes? You can use a Timer and poll for chages every minute or whatever. You can then call the method john recommended from the timer.Tick or even the button3_Click(null,null)

Comment: By price changes I mean, for example: I click the button, and $1000 is displayed in the richtextbox. I click it again, now $2000 is displayed in the texbox just below the $1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I click the button, and $1000 is displayed in the richtextbox. I click it again, now $2000 is displayed in the texbox just below the $1000.

You should then use `richTextBox.AppendText` instead of `richTextBox.Text`.

```
...
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(richTextBox1.Text) 
    this.richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

richTextBox1.AppendText("BTC Price: " + o["ticker"]["price"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not repeat the event, but rather move your desired piece of a code into a separated method and invoke it whenever needed.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateData();
}

private void ValidateData()
{
    if (textBox4.Text == "BTC")
    {
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        var data = c.DownloadString("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd");
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
        richTextBox1.AppendText("BTC Price: " + o["ticker"]["price"]);
    }
}
```

Then you can append an OnChange event to your control and execute ValidateData each time the user changes his input.